# programmatically check the correctness of the SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, parsing

I have a form wherein the users input sql queries for different reports. I want to check the validity of the sql before I save it to the database. How can I achieve this in vb.net

I looked at http://www.sqlparser.com, anything other than this ?

Comment: What's the main reason your users must input "sql queries" to use your app? `I want to check the validity of the sql before I save it to the database` what do you mean by that?

Comment: [See this CodeProject post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410081/Parse-Transact-SQL-to-Check-Syntax)

Comment: @the_lotus and what if the query is "delete all"? That will probably run without error

Comment: @Devcon: It app is used to input sql queries. I want to check the correctness of the sql query so that it doesnt error out when it runs on  in the database